# listing csv files using python re.match

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have created a small code in python to list csv files in the current directory:

```
>>> for i in range(len(os.listdir())):
...     isMatch = re.search(r'\.csv$', os.listdir()[i])
...     if (isMatch):
...             print(os.listdir()[i])
...
HR_data.csv
HR_data2.csv
HR_data_WEKA.csv
WholesaleCustomersData.csv
>>>
```

Is there a more elegant and shorter way to do this, like using lambda expressions???
Thanks very much./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex, and `glob` has overhead. Just use the inbuilt `str.endswith` function:

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        print(filename)
```

Also, it is more efficient to iterate over the elements in a list directly than iterating over the indices and then referencing the list. Especially when you consider, you keep calling `os.listdir()` everytime you want to access the `ith` file, which is extremely wasteful.

---

Here's an elegant alternative with `filter`:

```
for csv_files in filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.csv'), os.listdir()):
    print(csv_files)
```

Works on both python2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

```
from glob import glob

for f in glob('*.csv'):
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using regex, you could try using Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.csv')
for f in files:
    print(f)
```